# Can't import cv2 package in jupyter notebook

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

In VS Code I created a virtualenv, installed opencv and wrote a few functions. The functions (which import cv2) work fine when running from terminal.

I now want to use those functions to collect some data in a jupyter notebook, so I added the venv kernel to jupyter, but when I try to import cv2 it says `No module named 'cv2'`
[image]

The venv is located in `projects\francine\venv` so everything looks right.

Comment: You should check `sys.executable` to see whether you are using the correct interpreter for the notebook.

Comment: I did this and it's reporting my main python installation, not the venv. Why does `!which python` report the venv's python installation f it's not using the venv?

Comment: Perhaps the `which jupyter-notebook` executable belongs to the main python interpreter environment, not venv. Make sure you have activated the venv and run `pip install notebook` with the correct pip.

Comment: Ah that's it! I thought I could run jupyter with the main python install, and inside there tell it to use the kernel from the venv. Seems that you have to install jupyter in the venv and both run jupyter from the venv and use the venv's kernel.